# While using OpenCV and JavaCV program gives error

Tags: java, c++, opencv, netbeans, javacv

I am trying to use OpenCV 2.4.9 and JavaCV 0.7 in NetBeans followed a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE) without success:

It gives error on this line:    Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_highgui in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.(opencv_highgui.java:79)
    at com.forms.VirtualDressingApp.startCamera(VirtualDressingApp.java:87)
    at com.forms.VirtualDressingApp.(VirtualDressingApp.java:73)
    at com.forms.VirtualDressingApp$11.run(VirtualDressingApp.java:603)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp5092527754081\jniopencv_highgui.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:700)
    ... 20 more

Anybody faced similar problem?

Comment: Have you tried the source provided by that site?

Comment: yes. I tried everything